# SQL Server 2014 Command Equivalent of data dump

Tags: sql-server, database

I was wondering if this is possible.

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio to do the following

```
Right Click database >
    Tasks >
        Generate Scripts... >
            Select specified database objects >
                dbo.table01 >
                    Save script to a specified location
                    File Name : C:\Users\admin\Documents\table01.sql
                    (Types of data to script : Data only)
```

So I'm just creating that nice SQL Server Backup of the data in my table.
Is it possible to do this in the command line though?

I'd like to automate this tedious process

Comment: [Off-topic] I wont consider this as my backup. When you have foreign key constraints then, while inserting back you need to insert the parent before inserting the child which might be very tedious process

Comment: wouldn't it just insert exactly the same data as it has output? Also I'm unable to use the Generate Script to do Schema and Data because the output file is 6GB so I can't open it with my text editor to import it into a different database